# C# -- XElement.SetValue("value") does nothing, returns nothing

Tags: c#, xml, setvalue

My code more or less boils down to this:

```
XDocument memberDB = XDocument.Load("my-path.xml");
var rank = memberDB.Descendants... Blah blah (this part works)
foreach (var g in rank) {
  g.SetValue("thing");
}
```

I've already gotten the selector working, so that's not the problem, and no error message is returned. Code after the g.SetValue line is still executed, but the XML document remains unchanged. What do?

Comment: Make sure you are getting into foreach loop, the rank isn't null, and that you check to see that memberDB has new values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save your document after editing.

```
memberDB.Save("my-path.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi so the **memberDB** is the document, the **rank** is not a reference to the document and neither is **g**. So how would **memberDB** know that it should change the values if only **rank** and **g** are getting the new value?

Comment: I don't know? Can you explain?

Comment: You need to get the updated values from **rank*** back to the **memberDB**. If you want to save the values from memberDB to be saved in the xml file you need to use the save command.